# SVG and d3: Draw primitive rectangle in data coordinates?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to learn d3 for building visualizations; as part of this project, I found I needed to draw some filled rectangles. This should be straightforward in SVG coordinates, but I want to draw in data coordinates. I cannot figure out why any of the rectangles would ever be drawn outside the canvas, but that's what I've observed in my minimal (not) working example here: https://bl.ocks.org/emprice/faed364cb1bc4cc1b0dcf8a5a2d50dac.

The pink rectangle actually goes outside the boundaries of the SVG element, which doesn't make sense if I've set up the x- and y-mappings correctly. Is there a trick for drawing in data coordinates that I haven't used, or have I configured the scales incorrectly? I've tried changing up the y scale parameters (range and domain) without success; the x scale, which is set up the same way, appears to work as expected.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I'll not address the coordinates issue, which was covered in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45133432/5768908), but I'll give you two important advices:

1. **Do not mix jQuery and D3**: not only this is unnecessary, but it also can break things sometimes. Just get rid of that jQuery code.
2. **Do not use a loop to bind data**: use the D3 idiomatic data binding.

Regarding point #2, since your data is an object and the `data` method does not accept an object, let's turn it into an array...

```
var dataArray = [];

for (var key in data) {
    dataArray.push({
        category: key,
        y1: data[key][0].y1,
        y0: data[key][0].y0,
        x1: data[key][0].x1,
        x0: data[key][0].x0,
    })
}
```

... which we can use for idiomatically bind the data:

```
g.selectAll(null)
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = {
    "cat1": [{
      "y1": 1.581699235490658,
      "y0": 0.8124126240209036,
      "x0": 0.0003786444528587656,
      "x1": 0.23513820522529344
    }],
    "cat2": [{
      "y1": 1.438932516124979,
      "y0": 0.7292493003174502,
      "x0": 0.0003786444528587656,
      "x1": 0.3029155622870125
    }, {
      "y1": 0.816326356719349,
      "y0": 0.7577181178689592,
      "x0": 0.471790988262022,
      "x1": 1.0
    }],
    "cat3": [{
      "y1": 1.04308128481062,
      "y0": 0.5216497481615152,
      "x0": 0.0,
      "x1": 0.3029155622870125
    }, {
      "y1": 1.2796737272400311,
      "y0": 0.5443780228140943,
      "x0": 0.471790988262022,
      "x1": 1.0
    }],
    "cat4": [{
      "y1": 0.8577183187799378,
      "y0": 0.5507803277857598,
      "x0": 0.44377129875047333,
      "x1": 0.4714123438091632
    }],
    "cat5": [{
      "y1": 1.411106314679798,
      "y0": 0.6447611230842676,
      "x0": 0.3032942067398713,
      "x1": 0.4714123438091632
    }],
    "cat6": [{
      "y1": 0.9875866563383724,
      "y0": 0.5832528539336078,
      "x0": 0.2355168496781522,
      "x1": 1.0
    }],
    "cat7": [{
      "y1": 1.2362146708036688,
      "y0": 0.2743087520017313,
      "x0": 0.3032942067398713,
      "x1": 0.44339265429761454
    }]
  };

  var dataArray = [];

  for (var key in data) {
    dataArray.push({
      category: key,
      y1: data[key][0].y1,
      y0: data[key][0].y0,
      x1: data[key][0].x1,
      x0: data[key][0].x0,
    })
  }

  // define the dimensions of the graph pane
  var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
  };
  var width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right;
  var height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // define the scale 
  var x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]).domain([0., 1.]);
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, height]).domain([0., 2.]);
  var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  g.selectAll(null).data(dataArray).enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.x0);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.y0);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return y(d.y1) - y(d.y0);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return z(d.category);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: As always, very useful information. Unneeded jquery and d3 combos always makes me cringe a little bit inside, as do loops to append features.

Comment: indeed. A panda dies every time someone mixes jQuery with D3.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that svg coordinates start from the top, and height extends the rectangle downwards. If you replace this line:

```
 .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
```

with

```
 .attr("y", function(d) { return height- y(d.y0); })
```

You will get something that should look more right.

---

Take for example a rectangle that has y coordinates of y1: 2 and y0: 0. This rectangle is intended to fill the entire height of the svg. Using your scale:

```
 var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]).domain([0., 2.]);
```

and your y placement:

```
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
```

You will be placing the top of this rectangle at the bottom of the svg. The scale will return a value equal to `height` for a input y value of 0. Anything placed with an svg y coordinate of `height` is at the bottom of the svg.

The height of the rectangle will also be equal to `height` and as such the rectangle will then extend downwards off the svg (part of the rectangle will be visible simply because of the margin using your code).

Instead, this rectangle should appear at the top, and extend all the way down, in order to do this, subtract the scaled value from `height`, and the rectangle will appear at the top of the svg.

---

If you want an input y value of zero to appear at the bottom of the screen, rather than the top (ditching SVG convention for a more typical Cartesian setup), then you need to change a little bit for your scale:

```
 var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, height]).domain([0., 2.]);
```

and height:

```
 .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y1) - y(d.y0); })
```

and change it so that you place the top coordinate at the top of the rect:

```
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
```